# OpenLayers serving a MapServer layer: data won't display correctly without using WMS

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wms, mapserver

I am trying to serve my Mapfile data as a MapServer layer in OL, rather than a WMS layer.

When I display it using WMS, everything works fine. The part of the mapfile I have struggled with was SIZEUNITS. Seems easy enough, but I encountered some strange behavior along the way.

The issue: my SIZEUNITS units is miles and the size is 100 (so a 50 mile radius). When I use the WMS layer below, everything is fine:

```
var cust = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("POIs",
"http://192.168.2.164/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/data2/html/html2/david_POIs4.map",
{layers: ['POIs']}, {wrapDateLine: true, singleTile: true});
```

However, when I try to switch it over to:

```
var cust = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer("POIs",
"http://192.168.2.164/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe",
{map: "/data2/html/html2/david_POIs4.map",
layers: ['POIs']}, {singleTile: true} );
```

The points (circles rather, with points in the middle) are HUGE. More or less taking up the whole map.

So, why would switching from WMS to MapServer show such glaring differences? A MapServer layer should be simpler to correctly configure.

When I was stuck on a similar issue last week I posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66213/mapserver-mapfile-and-openlayers-using-sizeunits-labels-shrinking-on-1x-zoom-a) (of course hadn't gotten this far yet).

Edit: see the images [here](https://imgur.com/a/DhK3Y) for a visual. First map is correct (zoomed in), 2nd map is incorrect.

Edit2: I've never had an issue with projections before (I have the same projection set in both the `LAYER` and the `MAP`). Here's the layer in question, and if I use `SIZEUNITS MILES` it seems to automatically get blown out of proportion, regardless of the value you pass to `SIZE` within `STYLE`.

```
    LAYER
            NAME POIs
            DEBUG 5
            TYPE POINT
            CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
            CONNECTION 'PointsOfInterest_Latest.db'
            DATA 'POIs'
            STATUS ON
            SIZEUNITS miles
            LABELITEM "name"
            CLASS
                    STYLE
                            SYMBOL 'Airport'
                            COLOR 8 29 118
                            #WIDTH 5
                            SIZE 10
                            #MINWIDTH 1
                            #MAXWIDTH 1
                    END
                    #STYLE
                    #       SYMBOL 'City'
                    #       COLOR 8 29 118
                    #       SIZE 6
                    #END
                    LABEL
                            FONT "andalewt"
                            TYPE truetype
                            ENCODING "UTF-8"
                            MINSIZE 9
                            MAXSIZE 9
                            POSITION AUTO
                            PARTIALS FALSE
                            COLOR 8 29 118
                            OFFSET 1 1
                            PRIORITY 10
                            BUFFER 0
                    END # LABEL
            END

            PROJECTION
                    "proj=latlong"
                    "ellps=WGS84"
                    "datum=WGS84"
            END
    END
```

Now, you can see the `SIZEUNITS` set to `MILES` and the `SIZE` set to 10. Being the farthest zoom level out, you should barely be able to see the circles, but they are huge, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbtvq.png).

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set `UNITS dd` in the `MAP` level. Big thank you to fellow user from MapServer mailing list.

He was saying `UNITS dd` is automatically set using WMS, but not MapServer. Good to know.

***"You are probably missing a "UNITS dd" at the map level. It works with
WMS because the SRS included in the WMS call will set the map.units to
dd automatically."***

Comment: What do you ean MAP level? Where exactly do you set the UNITS to dd? And what format is your layer above in? I'm new to OpenLayers, so not familiar with everything. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I-B, MAP level is the 'outermost' level in the Mapfile. Just add it somewhere at the top before you start your LAYER definitions. Not sure what you mean by format? It's just a database (lat and long are stored in there, along with other columns). Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Oh, okay, so Mapfile is specific to MapServer? I installed GeoServer to begin, so that's probably why I'm not familiar with it. Thanks for the help. And for what format, I just meant the information you're showing above. I didn't know if that was like XML or what. With the STYLE/END stuff. I'll have to install MapServer and check it out sometime.

Comment: I'm a novice myself but yes I'm fairly certain if you want to generate a Mapfile you need to be using MapServer. As for format, you'll see `LABELITEM "name"`. name is a column in my database, so that will be used to display the data. The documentation is actually quite handy for configuring Mapfiles.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at it right now. Thanks again. http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/